# What is the best approach if I want external customers to be able to read certain wiki Pages inside my Publishing Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, publishing-site

I have implemented the following:-

- A Publishing site which include 5 Enterprise Wikis sub sites.
- Currently this publishing site is linked to our company active directory, and only internal users are able to access the publishing site.
- For each sub site certain users can contribute while other users are allowed to only read the wiki pages.

What I am trying to achieve:-

- **Requirement 1**. Currently the management is asking if we can allow external customers to login to our SharePoint application.
- **Requirement 2**. To allow authenticated external customers to read certain Wikis. Baring in mind that these Wikis can be under different wiki categories and sub sites.

To achieve this I am thinking of the following:-

1. To achieve the first requirement; I thinking of creating a new user for each external customer inside our active directory. So that they will be able to login to SharePoint application, after sending them the username and password.
2. While to achieve the second requirement; I am thinking of :-

   - Creating new term set inside our metadata navigation tree representing our customers. As shown in the below picture.
   - And if certain Wiki should be accessible by certain user I can tag this Wiki with the customer name.
   - For each Wiki page I can add the customer to the “Restricted Reader” User Group.

So will my approach work well, or I should consider different approach to follow.

Best Regards

[image]

Comment: Where is the picture that you were suppose to show? "As shown in the below picture." But I think your approach might work well.

Comment: i have added the picture ..